# Issues in exceution while run the test script through Maven

Tags: maven, selenium

While i am executing my test script through maven test, it shows error. below are the errors at runtime.

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Talentrack V1 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
>   [INFO] Downloaded:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
>   (11 KB at 4.5 KB/sec) [INFO] Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.12.4/surefire-2.12.4.pom
>   [INFO] Downloaded:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.12.4/surefire-2.12.4.pom
>   (14 KB at 21.1 KB/sec) [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Talentrack
>   --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non
>   existing resourceDirectory
>   D:\Talentrack_talent\Talentrack\src\main\resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ Talentrack ---
>   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [WARNING] File
>   encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build
>   is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling 10 source files to
>   D:\Talentrack_talent\Talentrack\target\classes [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK? [INFO] 1 error [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 4.087 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2016-05-17T16:35:05+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/121M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project Talentrack: Compilation failure [ERROR]
>   No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK? [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To
>   see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Do you have JDK installed and is your JAVA_HOME pointing to your JDK location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Compilation failure [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this
>   environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

You need to specify the JDK path into your *system variables / bash profile* which can be done by adding a JAVA_HOME variable to it.